# How to assign a single column of a multi dimensional array to a single dimensional one?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a one dimensional array from the first column of a two dimensional array, in C#. But this code does not seem to work

```
string[,] twoDArray;
//Some values are added to the array here

string[] oneDArray = twoDArray[,1];
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create a new array and fill it in a loop

```
string[,] twoDArray = new [,] {{"1","2"}, {"3","4"}, {"5","6"}};
int len = twoDArray.GetLength(0);
string[] oneDArray = new string[len];

for(int r=0;r<len; r++)
    oneDArray[r] = twoDArray[r,1];
```